# Make a speaking messagebox in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, audio, messagebox

I lately knew how to make visual basic speak. But the thing I want is Mesage box speaking. I tried following but at first the message box was shown. And when i press Ok then only the audio was played.

```
         MsgBox("Please select the Genre of movie you want to give.")
          SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
        SAPI.Speak("Please select the Genre of movie you want to give.")
```

and when I tried putting msgbox at down then at first the audio was played then messagebox was shown. 
 And when i tried

```
             SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak.Msgbox("Please select the Genre of movie you want to give.")
```

Then  " An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number." error was given. I tried to show the message box and play the audio with it. But couldnt do. Please somebody help me out for this

Comment: You can try looking into the concept of [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eed6swsx(v=vs.71).aspx) to execute multiple tasks simultaneously.

Comment: Which line was the exception thrown on? It's expecting you to pass more than one parameter in one of the two functions you call.